# If column data empty, push data to left

Tags: sql, oracle

When I do:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

table of 6 columns

I get something like this:

[image]

But I would like to get something like this:

[image]

I've tried the following:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(col-1,''), 
                NULLIF(col-2,''), 
                NULLIF(col-3,''), 
                NULLIF(col-4,''), 
                NULLIF(col-5,''), NULLIF(col-6,''))
```

With this, I get the first non empty column, but how to get all the next if there are?

Or is there another solution?

Comment: Your question indicates, that your database is not even in 1NF.
Consider normalizing your db.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot data, sort them by column which moves nulls to last position and pivot again to the original form:

```
select *
  from (
    select rn, row_number() over (partition by rn order by col) rc, val
      from (select rownum rn, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 from mytable)
      unpivot (val for col in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)))
  pivot (max(val) for rc in (1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3, 4 col4, 5 col5, 6 col6))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d9a99734629056dc1d55559cc7c6f1a)</sup>**

If you have some unique `id` in your table use it instead of `rn`. If you want to sort data according to their data, not position, change `order by` in `row_number()`. Pivot and unpivot requires Oracle 11 or later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `case` expressions.  This is cumbersome logic but probably faster than moving data between rows and columns:

```
select (case when col5 is null then col6
             when col4 is null then col5
             when col3 is null then col4
             when col2 is null then col3
             when col1 is null then col2
             else col1
        end) as col1,
       (case when col5 is null then null
             when col4 is null then col6
             when col3 is null then col5
             when col2 is null then col4
             when col1 is null then col3
             else col2
        end) as col2,
       (case when col5 is null then null
             when col4 is null then null
             when col3 is null then col6
             when col2 is null then col5
             when col1 is null then col4
             else col3
        end) as col3,
       . . .
from t;
```